# How to convert ClientTemplate from Telerik MVC to Kendo

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik MVC Grid like

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid<Model>()
.Name("Athletes")
...
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(a => a.IsNew)
         .ClientTemplate("<span <#= IsNew ? \"class='t-icon t-update'\" : \"\" #>></span>")
...
```

What ClientTemplate does is to display an icon of yes checkmark in the column of grid if IsNew is true.

Now I want to make above code work in Kendo Grid and ClientTemplate. I am not sure how to do it. "t-icon" and "t-update" look like icon image but I can not find them in the project. I need help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect the CSS of the span element - the icons are most likely part of a sprite. (`background:url` with offsets)

Comment: Yes, it is related to sprite. But I still can not understand the meaning of t-icon and t-update, as well as how they are related to sprite images.

Comment: there is a rule in the css that says if an element has these two classes, show this section of the sprite as background of said element; not sure what it is you don't understand; maybe read this: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-sprites.php

Comment: maybe you should use Kendo UI icons instead?

Comment: Thanks. How to use Kendo UI icons?

Comment: just take a look at the demos; e.g. for grid popup editing, the update button: <span class="k-icon k-update"></span> will show the check mark (and it's probably the equivalent to the one you mentioned in the question)

Comment: I understand that class='t-icon t-update' is telerik icon of update. Where can it be found?